# Xlwings UDF throwing an error on working code

Tags: python, excel, user-defined-functions, xlwings

I have been working on a project with xlwings where you input travel details and it runs through a UDF to return the average flight price from the Skyscanner API. It works fine in PyCharm and even in excel when I call the function by typing in the data manually. However, it throws an error when I call the function  by using the cells (i.e. =airfare("DCA", "LAX", "08-11-2022", "08-20-2022") vs =airfare(D7, J7, D5, J5)).

The error it is throwing is a key error, which doesn't make any sense because it should not run at all if that was the case. I've included the function code, the error code, as well as a screenshot of the excel sheet itself if that's helpful. Thank you for any help!

Function:
`@xw.func
def airfare(home_iata, dest_iata, dept_date, return_date):

```
home_iata = str(home_iata)
dest_iata = str(dest_iata)
dept_date = str(dept_date)
return_date = str(return_date)

url = "https://skyscanner44.p.rapidapi.com/search"

querystring = {"adults": "1",
               "origin": home_iata,
               "destination": dest_iata,
               "departureDate": dept_date,
               "returnDate": return_date,
               "cabinClass": "economy",
               "currency": "USD"}

headers = {
    "X-RapidAPI-Key": "999ed112f4msh46e340c8981b3bdp12b642jsn92be398dab25",
    "X-RapidAPI-Host": "skyscanner44.p.rapidapi.com"
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, verify=False, headers=headers, params=querystring).json()

flights_only = response["itineraries"]["buckets"]

# Get average of all prices
# Variables for totals/counts to divide by
count = 0
total = 0
best_total, best_count = 0, 0

for i in flights_only:
    category = i["id"]
    for j in i["items"]:
        current_price = j["price"]["raw"]

        if category == "Best":
            count += 1
            total += current_price
            best_count += 1
            best_total += current_price

# Average dict for easier access when printing
average = round(best_total / best_count, 2)

return average`
```

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXAqm.png)

[Excel Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBhjS.png)

Comment: The error seems to complain that `response` doesn’t contain a key called “itineraries”.  Check what `home_iata` etc variables actually contain before they are passed to the query, and also what response actually contains. Try substituting each parameter one by one. If I had to guess it would be the dates that are causing the problem. Are they in the spreadsheet as strings, or as an Excel Date (ie a number)?

Comment: @DS_London Everything checks out on the code side, it runs perfectly fine inside PyCharm. It is only when I run it inside Excel (using the exact same parameters) that it returns the keyerror.

Comment: Just print out `querystring` before you send the request. It is hard to tell from your screenshot whether the Excel cell for Departure Date contains a String or a Date (a double) which just looks like a string. My suspicion is that `str(dept_date)` is not returning `2022-08-12` as it converts the passed Excel date value to a string.

Comment: I think you may be right with that @DS_London. When I print out the querystring the dates are returning as the date + the 00:00:00 afterwards. I am using the datetime package on a different function within the file, so I'm not sure if that could be causing an issue as well. However, it is still running fine when I run the app in pycharm. Any idea on how to get the app to just read the date as a string?

Comment: You should print out `type(dept_date)`. I don't know `xlwings` so not sure what type conversion it might be doing. It is quite possible that it has converted `dept_date` to a python `datetime` type. If so, you could try `dept_date.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')` to create the string you want.  https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior